# Deserialize nested Json data with Newtonsoft in C# and assign into variable

Tags: c#, json

Here is the Json data that I got

```
{
"Data": {
"namelist": [
  {
    "name": "Elson Mon",
    "Information": {
      "Age": 45.0,
      "Height": 168.7,
      "Weight": 75.4,
      "Birthdate": "1992-03-03"
    },
    "Married Status": "Single"
  }
]
}
}
```

And here are my models

```
public class Information
{
     public double Age { get; set; }
     public double Height { get; set; }
     public double Weight { get; set; }
     public string Birthdate { get; set; }
}

public class Namelist
{
     public string name { get; set; }
     public Information Information { get; set; }
     public string MarriedStatus { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
     public List<Namelist> namelist { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
     public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

How can I deserialize the Json format string and assign into variable ?
I'm trying to use

`dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`

to deserialize the Json data but have totally no idea on how to assign it into different variable.

Comment: `RootObject jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I right in assuming your problem is actually assigning the result to a variable?

If that's the case, you needn't bother figuring out the type (although it's pretty obvious here - you're deserializing a string into RootObject, so if this works, you'll naturally have a RootObject). Just let the compiler do it for you:

```
var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

You can then hover over "var" to see the type. It's much more convenient when you really have no idea what you're working with or if the type is something rather ugly like `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>>`.

Avoid the dynamic type in such cases; always prefer putting the actual type or "var". The compiler doesn't know what you've got if you store it in a dynamic, so it won't issue any warnings if you're using your object in an inappropriate way, you'll face the consequences run-time.

Comment: Ya, your assumption is right,After i deserialize the Json file, do I able to assign like "name" into one varable and "Elson Mon" to another variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right path.

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = @"{
                    'Data': {
                    'namelist': [
                      {
                        'name': 'Elson Mon',
                        'Information': {
                          'Age': 45.0,
                          'Height': 168.7,
                          'Weight': 75.4,
                          'Birthdate': '1992-03-03'
                        },
                        'Married Status': 'Single'
                      }
                    ]
                    }
                    }";

    RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
}
```